# Create adapter from openapi-generator to react-query on Typescript

Tags: typescript, openapi

I have got classes generated by openApi generator. Every class method ends with HTTP method name, for expample 'deleteBookUsingDELETE' or 'getBookUsingGET'. For every method in class should be corresponding react-query hook created. When method ends with GET, useQuery hook should be used, for the rest of HTTP methods use useMutation.
The problem is: how create type safe adapter?
Example of openApi generated class(implementation removed).

```
export class MetricControllerApi extends runtime.BaseAPI {


async byEndpointUsingGETRaw(requestParameters: ByEndpointUsingGETRequest): Promise<runtime.ApiResponse<MetricDtoResponse>> {

}


async byEndpointUsingGET(requestParameters: ByEndpointUsingGETRequest): Promise<MetricDtoResponse> {
  
}


async byOwnerUsingGETRaw(requestParameters: ByOwnerUsingGETRequest): Promise<runtime.ApiResponse<MetricResponse>> {

}


async byOwnerUsingGET(requestParameters: ByOwnerUsingGETRequest): Promise<MetricResponse> {

}


async byTopicUsingGETRaw(requestParameters: ByTopicUsingGETRequest): Promise<runtime.ApiResponse<MetricResponse>> {

}


async byTopicUsingGET(requestParameters: ByTopicUsingGETRequest): Promise<MetricResponse> {
  
}
}
```

Not type safe adapter, which i managed to write

```
  export class Adapter<T extends object> {
      constructor(private readonly controllerApiInst: T) {
      }
    
      generate(): Record<keyof T, CallableFunction> {
        const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this.controllerApiInst);
        const res = (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype) as (keyof T)[])
          .filter(fieldOrMethod => {
            if (typeof prototype[fieldOrMethod] === 'function') {
              return true;
            }
          })
      .reduce((acc: any, v: keyof T) => {
        acc[v] = <P, R>(req: P): R => {
          return (this.controllerApiInst[v] as CallableFunction)(req);
        };

        return acc;
      }, { ...prototype });

    return res;
  }
}
```

Use example:

```
const configuration = new Configuration({
  basePath: 'test'
});
export const metricsController= new MetricControllerApi(configuration);

const check = new Adapter(metricsController);
const res = check.generate();
```

Comment: Looks like `@openapi-codegen/typescript` has an option to generate react-query hooks. See this great post: https://xata.io/blog/openapi-typesafe-react-query-hooks

Comment: Rapini looks like another option: https://rametta.org/posts/rapini-react-query-openapi-codegen/

Comment: And, here's yet another, called Orval: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/lzznti/orval_reactquery_code_generation_for_openapi/

Comment: Yet another option: https://github.com/astahmer/openapi-zod-client combined with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zodios/react

Comment: Alright I'm going to bed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query-swagger

Answer (score 6):

Hello if you're still looking for a lib that  generate openapi client for react-query: i found a pretty one and production ready: https://github.com/anymaniax/orval